# Printing String in ip address style

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have an array `fip[i]` which contains `[10101100, 00010000, 00001010, 00000000]`.`fip1` is taking the value in decimal one by one. Finally I would like to store the value in the `abc` variable like an IP address and print it:

```
172. 16. 10. 0
```

Code:

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
       {
        fip1[i] = Integer.parseInt(fip[i],2);
        if(i!=3) System.out.print(".");
       }
 abc = Arrays.toString(fip1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you are asking, but if it is "how to I store the IP address value in a String", you can just use the code you already have, but replace the *System.out.println* statements with calls to a *StringBuilder*.

For example...

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
   {
    builder.append(Integer.parseInt(fip[i],2));
    if(i!=3) builder.append(".");
   }

String abc = builder.toString();

System.out.println(abc); // Should print your IP address...
```

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestion. @Bret:Thanks for your suggestion.Its working now.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up the array and your output via `system.out.println()`'s

This is what you want:

```
String output = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    output += Integer.parseInt(fip[i], 2);
    if (i != 3)
        output += ".";
}
System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final String[] fip = { "10101100", "00010000", "00001010", "00000000" };
final StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (final String str : fip) {
    strBuilder.append(Integer.parseInt(str, 2));
    if (!fip[fip.length - 1].equals(str)) {
        strBuilder.append(".");
    }
}
System.out.println(strBuilder);
```